# En Jquery, como conseguir un numero aleatorio in un rango

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Por ejemplo, si mi rango es el siguiente

> [1,2,3,4]

Como conseguir uno de esos 4 numeros, sin decimal, solo pueden ser los enteros posibles 1 o 2 o 3 o 4..

de ser posible en jquery o javascript

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hasta el momento?, por favor coloca tu código a modo de [mcve]. Adicionalmente te invito a leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

La solución no involucra a Jquery. Puedes lograr lo que pides utilizando `Math.random` que te genera un número aleatorio en el intervalo de `[0,1)` y multiplicado por la longitud del arreglo el número quedaría entre `[0,4)`. Luego con `Math.floor` lo conviertes en un índice entero de tu arreglo.

Te adjunto una línea de código que puedes usar con cualquier arreglo de cualquier longitud. Ejecútalo varias veces:

```js
let miArreglo = [1,2,3,4]
let elementoAleatorio =miArreglo[Math.floor(Math.random()*miArreglo.length)];

console.log(elementoAleatorio)
```

Comment: Por favor, evita contestar a preguntas mal formuladas, es decir, que no cumplen con los lineamientos del sitio. El usuario no ha demostrado ningún intento por su parte, por lo cual esta pregunta terminará cerrada.